# In ruby, how do I use string.scan(/regex/) method for numbers from 1 to 12?

Tags: ruby, regex, numbers

That's what I am doing:

```
c.scan(/[1-9]|1[0-2]/)
```

For some reason, it returns only numbers from 1 to 9, ignoring the second part. I tried experimenting a little bit, it seems that the method will search for 10-12 only if 1 is excluded from [1-9] part, e.g., c.scan(/[2-9]|1[0-2]/) will do. What is the reason?

P.S. I know that this method lacks lookbehinds and will search for numbers and "part of numbers" as well

Comment: `c.scan(/\b10|11|12|\d\b/)` reads nicely, imo.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, ah, yes. Thanks. I'll leave me comment, as it and yours may have educational value, especially those who, like me, sometimes misuse `\b`.

Comment: Ah, yes, @AvinashRaj. Thanks. Let me change that to `c.scan(/\b(?:\d|10|11|12)\b/)`.

Comment: note that `\d` matches 0 also.. Op don't want that :-)

Comment: Anton, what do you want returned when `c = "03"`?

Answer (score 3):

Change the order of your patterns and add word boundaries if necessary.

```
c.scan(/\b(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])\b/)
```

The pattern before `|` is used first. So in our case, it matches all the numbers from 10 to 12. After that the next pattern, that is the one after `|` is used and now it matches all the remaining numbers ranges from 1 to 9. Note that this would match `9` in `59` also. So i suggest you to put your pattern inside a capturing or non-capturing group and add word boundary `\b` (*matches between a word character and a non-word character*) before and after to that group .

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/IkcKKpxXEx)

Comment: I just wanted to point out that using a non-capture group gives a slightly different result, which I expect would generally be preferable: `c = "13 123 1 23 11 7 111 31"; c.scan(/\b(1[0-2]|[1-9])\b/) #=> [["1"], ["11"], ["7"]]; c.scan(/\b(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])\b/) #=> ["1", "11", "7"]`.

Comment: thanks added... I don't think, using a capturing group would return a multi-dimen array in ruby..

Answer (score 0):

`|` matches left to right, and the first part of the right side (`1`) is always matched by the left side. Reverse them:

```
c.scan(/1[0-2]|[1-9]/)
```

Comment: I made a similar mistake, by forgetting to include both a non-capture group and `\b`'s (or lookarounds): `"100".scan(/1[0-2]|[1-9]/) #=> ["10"]`, `"101".scan(/1[0-2]|[1-9]/) #=> ["10", "1"]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: The asker didn’t ask for lookarounds (and made a specific note at the end of the question), so, no mistake.

Comment: I missed that, but no matter, it was just an alternative to `\b`'s. What do you mean, "no mistake"?.  Surely the OP doesn't want `"101"` to become `["10", "1"]`, or `"13"` to become `["1", "3"]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I have no idea what the OP wants. Their question was why the second part of the `|` never matched; nothing specifically more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you might consider extracting numbers between 1 and 12 (assuming that's what you want to do):

```
c = '14 0 11x 15 003 y12'
c.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).select { |n| (1..12).cover?(n) }
  #=> [11, 3, 12]
```

I've returned an array of integers, rather than strings, thinking that probably would be more useful, but if you want strings:

```
c.scan(/\d+/).map { |s| s.to_i.to_s }
 .select { |s| ['10', '11', '12', *'1'..'9'].include?(s) }
  #=> ["11", "3", "12"]
```

I see several advantages to this approach, versus using a single regex:

- it's easy to understand;
- the regex is simple;
- it's easy to modify if the permissible values change; and
- it can be broken into three pieces to facilitate testing.